# How to directly copy screenshot to slack/skype in Mac OS X like snipping does in windows

Tags: macos, mac, screenshot

In windows we have snipping tool. In which after grabbing the screen user can click on copy in snipping tool, now when user press control + v in skype and slack the stream screenshot pasted in chat section in skype , slack and microsoft teams

Mainly I am looking for something in mac where I don't need to save every screenshot and select file in slack/skype to sent them, it took much effort everytime with unnecessary screenshot files storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

macOS has more screenshot/snipping tool options than you could know what to do with…

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  - Capture entire screen[s]
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  - Capture selected area
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  then tap Spacebar - Capture next window clicked, with drop-shadow.
Add  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  to any of the above - Capture to clipboard instead of file.

and the new one since Mojave…
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  - Presents an interface to select from all of the above, plus cursor switch, timed modes, save location options & video recording alternatives.

As all these methods access the same underlying process, any prefs you set in the new  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  interface will be carried over into the other methods [except the timer, which you can only do with the new interface.]

Comment: the answer was lil different which I posted in answer section too but your answer helped me to lead it .. thanks

Comment: However, on MacOS 10.15.7 and Skype for Business 16.29.39, the cpoy paste feature does still not work.

Comment: @user637338 Then that will be a Skype issue, not a macOS issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am not debating this. It's just that when one searches for the issue, one lands here, amongst others. People who search for the issue might be under the impression that the keyboard shortcuts will lead to the solution. While the shortcuts are correct, Skype has just not implemented this feature in the stated version.

Comment: Cool! I did not know about an option to add `Ctrl` and save to the clipboard instead of a file.

Answer (score 2):

Extended Tetsujin answer -

Cmd ⌘ + cntl + Shift ⇧ 3 or 4

It will store in screenshot in clipboard/cache.

For permanent settings below are the steps:

**Using clipboard**

- Step 1 :- Cmd ⌘ Shift ⇧ 5
- Step 2 :- Now in option change the save to clipboard
- Step 3 :- Goto to slack or skype etc and press  Cmd ⌘ + v

**Using preview**

- Step 1 :- Cmd ⌘ Shift ⇧ 5
- Step 2 :- Now in option change the save to preview
- Step 3 :- From Menu -> Edit -> Copy
- Step 4 :- Goto to slack or skype etc and press  Cmd ⌘ + v

This is one time setup after that you can go for any option.

Now you do any type of screenshot option sets for all, i.e press cmd+4, it will do behave similarly

Comment: That's a bit long-winded, compared to simply adding Ctrl to any of the above options. If you capture to the clipboard you have already done the Copy part, all you need do is Paste. eg, Cmd/Ctrl/Shift/4, click-drag an area, paste. Done.

Comment: thanks .. thats correct .. using clipboard now even copy step is also done automatically .. voting you up